# getting permission denied error while executing N1QL query on couchbase 7.1 if result set is big

Tags: couchbase, sql++, spring-data-couchbase

I am executing following query statement whose result set contains 10000 documents, while running the query I get permission denied error. If the result sets are small then this error does not come.

query

```
delete from `A` where _type="typeA" and tenant = "B" and status="ACTIVE"
```

From the above query 10000 records to be deleted

Following is the err

```
[
  {
    "code": 5000,
    "msg": "open /data/tmp/scan-results428491556497897: permission denied - cause: open /tescodata/tmp/scan-results428491556497897: permission denied",
    "query": "delete from `A` where _type=\"typeA\" and tenant = \"B\" and status=\"ACTIVE\""
  },
  {
    "code": 5000,
    "msg": " open /data/tmp/scan-results428491556497897: permission denied - cause:  open /data/tmp/scan-results428491556497897: permission denied"
  }
]
```

Here the CB version is 7.1

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the following has read/write permissions

https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/backfill.html